# Page working with `grunt serve` but not when I load index.html

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, gruntjs

GitHub repo:  https://github.com/grahamlutz/MyVirtualPack

When I use grunt serve to start a server listening to `localhost:9000`, the page looks and works fine.  When I try to load index.html in the browser, I am not getting access to the bower_components folder, which is a folder above index.html in the directory.

```
GET file:///bower_components/modernizr/modernizr.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
index.html:190 GET file:///bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND               -      index.html:195
```

---

```
GET file:///bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/affix.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND                  - index.html:196
```

---

```
GET file:///bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/alert.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND                   -    index.html:196
```

...etc.

I am not sure what to ask exactly, expect that I don't know what is happening differently when utilizing grunt serve?

Comment: When you use `grunt serve` or any other server it'll use relative path of server and it'll work. When you run index.html without server, the filepath is not getting correct, so it'll not work.

Comment: Thanks @Tushar.  So is there a way to use relative path when running index.html?  Also, If/when I host this with something like goDaddy, will it use relative path?

Answer (score 1):

Actually your problem is caused by **absolute** paths: these start with '/' on lines 191 and more.
They work fine in the context of an `http:` request (grunt serve or your GoDaddy), but not on a simple `file:` request (which is what you get when you simply load a local file in your browser).

Replace them with relative paths (`../bower_components/[...]`) and you should be good - this might require some work on your wiredep configuration.